# Jump to a specific tab in a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabcontroller

I want to jump to third tab in tabcontroller. I searched in Google but found nothing helpful.

If anybody can help I will be grateful.

Comment: You "searched from google nothing helpful"?  What did you search for?  I searched for `jump to tab uitabbarcontroller` and the first hit has your answer.

Comment: sorry - i just  have to agree with Rob on this one. it's simply impossible to believe that you've searched for anything on google prior to asking this question.

Comment: Hi, I have searched in google. I got some examples I tried in my solution but nothing works for me.

Comment: I searched in Google and got here. How's that for a circular reference?

Answer (score 6):

Was the title/question changed? I thought the question was about Xcode...

For what you're asking, try setting `selectedIndex` of your UITabBarController, like this:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = indexOfTab;
```

However don't overuse it, some automatic transitions between tabs can be considered as bad user experience.

<s>Don't just stop with this shortcut - learn more! Here's an [extensive list of Xcode 4 shortcuts](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2011/03/xcode-4-keyboard-shortcuts-now.html): print the B&W version, pin it your wall, learn and enjoy the Xcode even more.</s>

Comment: Yes, the question was radically edited.  And those who answered the asked question are apparently being down voted.

Comment: It wasn't radically edited. You can see the edits, I only corrected it to make it clearer that he was asking about a tabbar controller. He mentions the controller in the question and in the tags. Some people get the IDE confused with the language. I just removed the references to Xcode.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replay. I have tried but failed. I have three tabs starts from left first one map, second vehicle number, third one Login.By default applications opened maps tab. `i want to go login tab. Can you please tell me how can I do this.

Answer (score 4):

You want to set the selectedIndex property of the tab controller

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks buddy i have seen this before.