# from tableview didselectrow to tabbarcontroller selected index

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

My iOS app has a UITabBarController with two tabs such as Player and Album ,with Player tab is selected by default and it has a ViewController with an audio player.When Album tab is selected it contains a UINavigationController on which a UITableView is placed,which shows several albums.When a particular album name is selected it pushes to another  ViewController showing the songs of that selected album.Now when I select a particular song,I want to pass the song url to the audio player which is found under player tab ,and I want to show the main tabbarcontroller .

For eg : consider the iPhone music player.We go through an album and when we select a song it shows the player screen ,how is it done ?

Comment: In this line "I want to pass the song url to the audio player which is found under **album** tab ,and I want to show the main tabbarcontroller ", i guess by mean album tab u mean player tab????

Comment: yes , i mean the player tab,my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should solve your issue `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = indexOfTab;`

For further reference

[UITabBarController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[Jump to a specific tab in a UITabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963450/jump-to-a-specific-tab-in-a-uitabbarcontroller)

Comment: I used the above code in my DidSelectRow. After selecting the song it didn't show up the player tab , it was just stuck there .

Comment: You actually have a call to pop to the root view controller.

Comment: I did like this in my DidSelectRow `NSString *albumURLstring = [addsongstring stringByAppendingString:mp3extension];       viewContObj = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    
    self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = viewContObj;
    
    viewContObj.url =[NSURL URLWithString:albumURLstring];

    [viewContObj createStreamer];
    [viewContObj playLiveStream:nil];`

Comment: see this link(http://www.ifans.com/forums/threads/overriding-uitabbarcontroller-behavior.209946/), you will understand.

Comment: After executing my code above . The url get passed and the song is played. But the player under my "player" tab is unaffected and static . Doesn't respond to the passed URL . So that means my player ViewController is not called yet,right?

Comment: if this is the only view in your player tab, then start your player in viewwillappear, it should work once you do that.

Comment: No change in my output. Where am i going wrong? when I select a item in tableview it is not showing my player controller and the player is not activated .